# mysql container access denied for user - docker compose

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-connector

I have a docker-compose.yml file which defines 3 containers: frontend, backend, and mysql database.

In my backend container I have a python code which uses "mysql" and "mysql.connector" libraries to connect to the database container.

However, when I run

```
docker-compose up
```

the container of the backend exits with code 1.
and I get this error:

[image]

my docker-compose.yml file looks like that:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mydb:
    container_name: mydb
    image: mysql
    env_file:
      - .env.mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysqld:/var/run/mysqld
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST:%
    #command: sh -c "mysql --execute="UPDATE mysql.user SET host='%' WHERE user='root';""
    # && mysql --execute="FLUSH PRIVILEGES;""
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysqladmin ping -h localhost" #this is mysql command to monitor if the localhost database is alive
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 60
      

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: back-dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "90:90"
    depends_on: 
      - mydb


  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: front-dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "8501:8501"
```

the ".env.mysql" file which defines the environment variables for the mysql container is:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
MYSQL_DATABASE=eass
```

and to make sure the container configured correctly here is a screenshot that shows the command env from inside the mysql container :
[image]

The piece of code that is used to connect to the mysql database is:

```
import mysql
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="mydb",
    user="root",
    passwd="123456",
    database="eass",
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)
```

how can I connect to the mysql database correctly?
thanks.

I tried to give `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST` either value of % or `172.20.0.04/255.0.0.0` - as i seen this was suggested on other closed discussions here.
I was expecting that the mysql container would accept the env % as all ips are granted to use root.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  What's the actual error you're getting?

Comment: ok, the error i get is : 
```mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.20.0.4' (using password:YES)```